Error Uploading Images: Limited to 50 Megapixels for gif image
I encountered an error message stating that image uploads are restricted to 50 megapixels on the a post however I thought the only limit was an image of any size <2MB. My image that is a gif is only 541 KB and yet I get the error Image uploads are limited to 50 megapixels; please use a smaller image when attempting to upload to a post. I've uploaded pics on SU with no problem on a previous post, but that was only a .png and not .gif. Is this a possible bug?
Edit:
I am still having the issue as of 6/18/2024


this is almost exactly at the same time the problem was supposed to have been fixed, Could you try again?

Relevant main meta post https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/398974/uploading-a-gif-doesnt-work-on-some-se-sites

Nope. Just tried again with the same gif image and still same error

works for me - could you upload the image somewhere that won't mangle it - zipping it up and putting it on wormhole.app might be an option so I can verify the issue and stick a status-review on it?

Here is the link of the image in a zip: https://wormhole.app/14Ed8#Cyc9EUQb1CYUbw-Y4q4K-A

Verified the bug - I've stuck a status-review on it, poked a community manager and I'll see what else's needed to sort out the issue

also if you're looking at the bug, and the link's borked, y'all know where to find me, and I'd be happy to reupload/temporarily host it somewhere :D

Awesome. Thanks for the help! Interesting to find the bug, but glad I was not crazy/lone wolf on the issue

@JourneymanGeek Still an issue. Wondering if this has any more attention?

unfortunately no updates yet.
